# Why is this Binary search algorithm returning None twice?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

Im starting to learn about Algorithms (using the grokkings algorithms book) and this is the binary search code that was in the book

```
def binary_search(list, item):

  low = 0
  high = len(list) - 1

  while low <= high: 
    mid = round((low + high) )
    guess = list[mid]
    
    if guess == mid:
      return mid

    if guess > mid: 
      high = mid - 1 

    else: 
      low = mid + 1

  return None

my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

print(binary_search(my_list, 3))
print(binary_search(my_list, -1))
```

The first one is supposed to return 1 but it returns None twice, anyone know why?

Comment: `mid = (low+high)/2` ? and `guess == item` ? and `guess > item`

Comment: don't you want to compare to `item` not `mid`?

Comment: Food for thought: Would this have happened if the variables were called `mid_index` &  `mid_value`?

Answer (score 3):

Try comparing `guess` with `item`:

```
def binary_search(lst, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(lst) - 1
    while low <= high: 
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        guess = lst[mid]
        if guess < item:
            low = mid + 1
        elif guess > item: 
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            return mid
    return None


my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(binary_search(my_list, 3))
print(binary_search(my_list, -1))
```

**Output:**

```
1
None
```

Comment: The `low + (high - low) // 2` trick isn't needed in Python, because Python ints don't overflow.  The commented code is better.

Comment: I wanted something different than the other answer, will remove.

Answer (score 0):

In the code is suppose to be mid = (low + high) // 2, where `//` is whole division.

Comment: There are more errors than that as this still returns `None`.